# Disable save file for default image in a picturebox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, picturebox

Basically I have a simple tool that loads an image into a picturebox from a url. I've added savefiledialog for people to save the image to their drives on click if they wish to do so.

On-load I have a default image display in the picturebox from resources.

My problem is that it allows people save the loaded default image. What I want to do is only allow them to save the images loaded from url not the actual default image that loads when the tool is started, sort of disable the savefiledialog if the image is the default one or something to that effect.

How do I go about this? Thanks.

Edit: The default image comes from resources and is on load. Everything works except I dont want them to save the default image, only the images they load manually.

Comment: Does the default image come from a local file or is it loaded from a resource?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean flag to your class indicating whether you've loaded a "real" image.

If that flag is false, don't show the dialog.